# JAXB unmarshalling works with lists, but not explicit properties

Tags: inheritance, jaxb

I am working on a program that represents formulas in first order logic as Java classes. I would like to be able to represent a formula in XML and use JAXB to instantiate a WFF object.

**Object Hierarchy**

The most generic object in a WFF is the abstract class Symbol. All Symbols have UUIDs, and can either be WFFs or Terms.

A Term is an abstract class extended by the final class Formula which has an arity and a list of Terms. It is also extended by the final class Variable which simply has a String name.

A WFF is an abstract class extended by Connective, Quantifier, and Relation. Each of these are extended by concrete types like Connective{And,Or,Not}, Quantifier{Universal,Existential}, RelationIn.

**Example XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<relationIn>
    <function name="inv">
        <variable name="X"/>
    </function>
    <variable name="X"/>
</relationIn>
```

**Example Class**

```
@XmlRootElement
public final class RelationIn extends Relation {    


    @XmlElementRef
    private Term t1;
    @XmlElementRef
    private Term t2;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private RelationIn() {
        this(null,null);
    }

    public RelationIn(Term t1, Term t2) {
        super();
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    @Override
    public WFF copy() {
        return new RelationIn(t1, t2);
    }

}
```

** Output **

Unmarshalling the XML to a WFF and then printing the results of marshalling the object results in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<relationIn id="aa348148-3e68-4540-9508-a2328b29acef">
    <variable name="X" id="951ce047-4bbe-40ad-a10e-e8bc94200aab"/>
</relationIn>
```

For some reason, t1 is always the second element in the xml, and t2 is always null in the object (evidenced by debugging, so I know the problem is not the marshalling). If I swap the order, t1 will be a function, and t2 will still be null. I've tried adding an @XmlType(proporder={"t1","t2"}), no joy.

However, if I instead use a single list of Terms, eg

```
@XmlElementRef
private List<Term> t;
```

the object gets created properly as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<relationIn id="80b21dec-f3f1-4871-9006-996e4cb2e1dc">
    <function name="inv" id="d7f80fca-ac6b-4785-9193-ba3d54e0cfa0">
        <variable name="X" id="cf9683f9-1d20-4b8a-aa40-121712426774"/>
    </function>
    <variable name="X" id="33961b28-37f3-45c5-b72a-e7265b3cd808"/>
</relationIn>
```

This is great, but I would like to just have two Terms instead of a collection of Terms if possible. Is there something obvious I am missing here? Any insights would be greatly appreciated, and I can provide more code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB expects each property to correspond to a unique element name in the XML, you can't map based on position.  This is why only one of the properties is populated with data.

Comment: Ah, so the XmlType proporder is only for marshalling? Is the List that is generated guaranteed to have the same order as the XML elements?

Comment: @Jonny - `propOrder` on `@XmlType` is for marshalling and schema generation.  Yes during marshalling a JAXB implementation will honour the ordering of objects in the `List`.

Comment: One more question -- is it possible to annotate my class somehow to make unmarshalling fail when the number of elements is incorrect? For example RelationIn requires 2 terms, so it should fail if any more or any less terms are in the document.

Comment: @Jonny - You can set an instance of `Schema` on the `Unmarshaller` and have the unmarshal operation validate against the XML Schema:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Comment: @Jonny - FYI, we do have position based mapping in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html